# Is it possible to use external function (Chrome extension) in my JS file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When loading Chrome extension, I am able to use the (for example) `function x()` from the console. I'm trying to write script when the page `onload` it will execute `x()` function... read about `eval()`... didn't go well...
is there any way to ask the console to execute `x()`?

Maybe someone have any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
window.onload = function() {
  x();
};
```